Whoever receives a child (literal), or one such a child (metaphor), receives Me
The text in Matthew 18:5 is pretty clear to me to mean a humble (adult) disciple of Jesus.
The text in Mark 9:37 might seem a little ambiguous.
The text in Luke 9:48 seems to refer directly to the little child in the room, therefore contradicting (?) Matthew.

5 And whoever receives one such child in My name, receives Me;
(Matthew 18:5)
37 “Whoever receives one child like this in My name receives Me; and
whoever receives Me does not receive Me, but Him who sent Me.” (Mark
9:37)
48 and He said to them, “Whoever receives this child in My name
receives Me, and whoever receives Me receives Him who sent Me; for the
one who is least among all of you, this is the one who is great.”
(Luke 9:48)

How can we reconcile the meaning of a child in Matthew 18:5 ("one such child") were it stands for a humble adult disciple of Jesus with the child in Luke 9:48 ("this child") where it refers directly to the little child in the room?

How can you be sure all three records are of the same incident ? Or whether Jesus made the same point at different times to different audiences and using slightly different wording ?

@NigelJ https://www.blueletterbible.org/study/harmony/index.cfm

all of the ideas and principles conveyed in the resource materials are not necessarily affirmed, in total, Blue Letter Bible statement. The so-called 'harmony' does not  substantiate the list of texts documented.

Jesus directly refers to a child present in all three passages:
Matthew 18:1-5

At that time the disciples came to Jesus, saying, “Who then is
greatest in the kingdom of heaven?”
2 Then Jesus called a little child to Him, set him in the midst of
them, 3 and said, “Assuredly, I say to you, unless you are converted
and become as little children, you will by no means enter the kingdom
of heaven. 4 Therefore whoever humbles himself as this little child is
the greatest in the kingdom of heaven. 5 Whoever receives one little
child like this in My name receives Me.

Mark 9:33-37

Then He came to Capernaum. And when He was in the house He asked them,
“What was it you disputed among yourselves on the road?” 34 But
they kept silent, for on the road they had disputed among themselves
who would be the greatest. 35 And He sat down, called the twelve, and
said to them, “If anyone desires to be first, he shall be last of all
and servant of all.” 36 Then He took a little child and set him in the midst of them. And when He had taken him in His arms, He said to them,
37 “Whoever receives one of these little children in My name receives
Me; and whoever receives Me, receives not Me but Him who sent Me.”

Luke 9:46-48

Then a dispute arose among them as to which of them would be greatest.
47 And Jesus, perceiving the thought of their heart, took a little child and set him by Him, 48 and said to them, “Whoever receives this
little child in My name receives Me; and whoever receives Me receives
Him who sent Me. For he who is least among you all will be great.”

In all three of these passages, the context is the disciples’ argument about who is the greatest in the kingdom of heaven. Jesus uses a child to teach about humility and true greatness.
The message is consistent across all three passages. It teaches that true greatness in the kingdom of heaven is about humility, servanthood, and valuing those who are humble and lowly.
No Contradiction:
By examining the context, we can see that Jesus is making a distinction between Christians and children while using the child as a metaphor for humility and lowliness.

There is a subtle distinction in the translation offered by the OP and that above. Which version are you using ? Up-voted +1.

@NigelJ Thank you for noting that. I used the NKJV. I left link directly to the verses if you click them individually. Although, you can also view them in parallel with other translations.

Let us examine the context of Matt 18:1-5 -

V2: Jesus calls a child to Him
V3 "as a little child"
V4: "as this little child"
V5: "such as this little child"

It is a natural progression to read in V6 "these little ones" as literal children.  Jesus, throughout this passage, is making a distinction between adult Christians and children.
Thus, Jesus encourages all Christians to treat children with respect.  Indeed, Jesus makes the mistreatment and abuse of children the hallmark and pinnacle of sinfulness of adults who so mistreat children.
The same is true in the parallel passages in Mark and Luke.
